# Convert timestamp to nanoseconds (Qt)

Tags: c++, qt, timestamp

I'd want to make something like this in Qt: given current timestamp convert it to nanoseconds.

Current solution doesn't give me the real nanoseconds value, only zeros after the timestamp value! Can someone help me, I didn't find anything like this in Qt.

Thank you for help.

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Comment: A timestamp is an instant in time, nanoseconds are a duration.  If you want nanoseconds, then what is the starting point of the epoch?  Start of today, 1 Jan 1970, 0 AD ?

Comment: [QElapsedTimer::nsecsElapsed()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qelapsedtimer.html)

Comment: Do you use a C++11 compiler ?

Comment: yes, i use C++11 compiler

Answer (score 2):

If using a C++11 compiler, you can use the `std::chrono` functions. No Qt, but it will work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
  std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> timestamp =
    std::chrono::system_clock::now();

  const auto ns = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>
    (timestamp.time_since_epoch()).count();

  std::cout << ns << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly why I was asking for C++11 ;)

Answer (score -2):

If you want the current timestamp in nano seconds, `QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch() * 1000000` does the trick.

Comment: Well, it still has milliseconds precision, but with six additional zeros.

Comment: On the original post, the OP did not give the detail that he wanted elapsed ns, just to convert ms timestamp to ns...

Comment: sorry for the miss understand, but yes, what @cbuchart said is to get nanoseconds and not zeros after the timestamp value

Answer (score -2):

You are looking for [QDateTime](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html) class. You could convert a given date time to a msecs since epoch or viceversa.

To convert a date time to msecs, use [toMSecsSinceEpoch](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#toMSecsSinceEpoch):

```
QDateTime currentDateTime = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
std::cout<< "Current DateTime : "
     << currentDateTime.toString().toStdString()
     << "\nCurrent DateTime in Milliseconds since epoch :\n"
     << currentDateTime.toMSecsSinceEpoch()
     << std::endl;
```

To convert to nanosecs, just convert from msecs to nanosecs:

```
const qlonglong nanosecs = currentDateTime.toMSecsSinceEpoch() * 1000000:
```

Viceversa, [fromMSecsSinceEpoch](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#fromMSecsSinceEpoch):

```
const qlonglong nanosecs = 5555555;
QDateTime myDateTime = QDateTime::fromMSecsSinceEpoch(nanosecs / 1000000);
```